# converting Python to Delphi code

Tags: python, http, delphi, indy

Next python code

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import urllib
import json

#ID access to API
TOKEN = "{YOUR_API_TOKEN}" # e.g.: "f03c3c76cc853ee690b879909c9c6f2a"
url = "https://cloudpanel-api.1and1.com/v1"

def _setStatusServer(id, content):
  #Configure the request
  _command = url + "/servers/" + id + "/status/action"
  _method = 'PUT'
  request = Request(_command, data=content.encode(encoding='utf_8'), 
                    headers={'X-TOKEN':TOKEN, 'content-
                    type':'application/json'}, 
                    method=_method)

   #Try to get the response
   try:
     response = urlopen(request)
     content = response.read()
     return (content.decode())
  #Fetch error
  except urllib.error.URLError as e:
      return("Error " + str(e.code) + ":" + e.reason) 

  #PARAMETERS
  id = "{YOUR_SERVER_ID}" # e.g.: "5340033E7FBBC308BC329414A0DF3C20"
  action = "REBOOT"
  method = "SOFTWARE"

  data = json.dumps({'action':action, 'method':method})

  #REBOOT server
  print(_setStatusServer(id, data))
```

I have converted to the pascal code

```
function TWFServerSetState.ExecuteCommand(id, ip_id, Content: string): string;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Command: string;
  InputStream: TStringStream;
  ResponseStream: TStringStream;

  str: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create();
  try
    HTTP.Request.ContentEncoding := 'UTF-8';
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-TOKEN', Token);
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('content-type', 'application/json');
    HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    Command := GetAddress + '/servers/' + id + '/status/action';

    str := '{"method": "' + Content + '", "action": "' + ip_id + '"}';
    str := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(STR, IndyUTF8Encoding);
    InputStream := TStringStream.Create(str, TEncoding.UTF8);
    ResponseStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8, false);
    try
      HTTP.Put(Command, InputStream, ResponseStream);
      Result := ResponseStream.DataString;
    finally
      ResponseStream.Free;
      InputStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But, result of execution of Python code is OK. 
Execution of Delphi code returns

"HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable"

Any suggestion where I made error in conversion?

Based on mjn suggestion I removed Mime encoding and changed url for test in both codes. Request from python code on the httpbin server is:

```
{'X-token': {token}, 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"method\": \"SOFTWARE\", \"action\": \"REBOOT\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "42", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Python-urllib/3.4", 
    "X-Token": "token"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "action": "REBOOT", 
    "method": "SOFTWARE"
  }, 
  "origin": "24.135.167.155", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/put"
}
```

from Delphi code

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"method\": \"SOFTWARE\", \"action\": \"REBOOT\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "42", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)", 
    "X-Token": "token"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "action": "REBOOT", 
    "method": "SOFTWARE"
  }, 
  "origin": "176.67.200.136", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/put"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Bojan

Comment: It seems you need to add  an Accept: header.

Comment: Do some debugging. Compare the two requests. How do they differ.

Comment: @David: I did that and I did not see any difference

Comment: That seems a little implausible don't you think

Comment: print(data) returns {"action": "REBOOT", "method": "SOFTWARE"}
print(request.headers) returns
{'X-token': {token}, 'Content-type': 'application/json'} - also all get methods work from delphi

Comment: Are you sure you can receive information from your server with this line of code "ResponseStream.DataString;" ?

Comment: In get methods that is possible.

Comment: also looking at python response that response is JSON

Comment: Capture the real HTTP requests and responses with a tool like Fiddler2 and compare them.

Comment: Notable difference: MIME encoding in the Delphi, but not in the original code. Also potential double UTF-8 encoding of the request body (IndyUTF8Encoding and TEncoding.UTF8).

Comment: PUT it to URL https://httpbin.org/put to get a first impression of what the server receives

Comment: "Notable difference: MIME encoding in the Delphi" - I tried and without str := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(STR, IndyUTF8Encoding);. Result was same.

Comment: Think about it. If the request is identical, the server will respond identically. That's how computers work. I posit that you haven't checked the request and don't know how to debug this.

Comment: "If the request is identical, the server will respond identically." - This is simple question. Everything what I checked is identical in Python and Delphi code. Only result is different. What I do not see?

Comment: Solution is in removing HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Delphi code is NOT sending the JSON data the same way the Python code is.  There are several logic and coding mistakes in your code.

The correct code should look more like this instead:

```
function TWFServerSetState.ExecuteCommand(const ServerID, Action, Method: string): string;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Url: string;
  InputStream: TStringStream;
  str: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-TOKEN', Token);
    HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    Url := GetAddress + '/servers/' + ServerID + '/status/action';
    str := '{"method": "' + Method + '", "action": "' + Action + '"}';
    InputStream := TStringStream.Create(str, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      try
        Result := HTTP.Put(Url, InputStream);
      except
        on e: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
          Result := 'Error ' + IntToStr(e.ErrorCode) + ':' + e.Message;
      end;
    finally
      InputStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var
  id, action, method: string;
begin
  id := '{YOUR_SERVER_ID}'; // e.g.: "5340033E7FBBC308BC329414A0DF3C20"
  action := 'REBOOT';
  method := 'SOFTWARE';
  ExecuteCommand(id, action, method);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have written the parameter names differently, because this class is one of the children's classes, and they all have different parameter names. Really only problem was in 
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('content-type', 'application/json');
    HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
because server saw this like 'application/json', 'application/json' and wasn't to accept this ContentType. httpbin.org/put wrote ContentType = 'application/json' only once, but the really server did not see it that way. Other was "addopted" correct.

Comment: @bojangavrilovic well, that, and you were base64 encoding the JSON data when the Python code didn't, and you were setting the `Content-Encoding` header to an invalid value. Those all added up to a very malformed request.